# How to create a stored procedure that creates a table at the end of the month, but the table name gets automatically generated based on system date

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, scheduled-tasks

Trying to create a stored procedure that updates each month on Snowflake:

Step1: Creating the Procedure

```
Create or replace procedure test_table()
Returns VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS '
BEGIN
   CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TEST_DATA_MARCH_2024 AS
   SELECT * FROM TEST_VIEW;
   RETURN ''Test snapshot for March'';
end;
';
```

Step 2: From the above Procedure, I have set up a task to refresh every month.

```
create or replace task Test_Task
warehouse = XYZ
SCHEDULE = 'using cron 0 7 1 * *'
as CALL test_table()

alter task Test_task resume
```

This logic will create the table on the first of every month at 7 AM,
Now I want to update the name of the table automatically, Instead of overwriting **TABLE TEST_DATA_MARCH_2024** I want the procedure to create the table name having the respective month and year name in it.

So for April 2024, The table created should be **TEST_DATA_APRIL_2024** instead of **TEST_DATA_MARCH_2024**.

any tips or tricks will help, Thanks

Comment: Hi - so what have you tried and what issue are you facing?

Comment: that is a colossal bad idea, if you use only 1 table all queries will be faster, and it will be less hassle if you need to combine the table vertically to get the whole year. such table construction are must be ussed in embedded systems else you should get far away frim that

Comment: Unless there is a strong need for creating monthly tables, a better design decision would be having one table with year and month columns and insert data from your source into this table once a month

Comment: Wanted to know if this was possible or not, and how you could go about this? I was using the month end table name in Power BI, so every month, I just change the table name in power bi and publish it. I also wanted to have the table for historical reference under the said table name based on year and month. If the table gets overwritten , then I would not have the data for the previous month. The main aim is to create a table that doesn't get overwritten so I can store the snapshot for historical data verification.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, Snowflake has `MONTHNAME` function returns 3 letter Month names. You can set a variable at the beginning of the stored proc and use in the table name

```
set dt = to_date('2024-04-01'); --replace with current_date()
set table_suffix = (select UPPER(MONTHNAME($dt-1)) || '_' || YEAR($dt-1));
select UPPER($table_suffix) will give you the value
```

[image]

To add the code to your SP

```
Create or replace procedure test_table()
Returns VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS '
BEGIN
   set dt = to_date('2024-04-01'); --replace with current_date()
   set table_suffix = (select UPPER(MONTHNAME($dt-1)) || '_' || YEAR($dt-1));
   CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TEST_DATA_$table_suffix AS
   SELECT * FROM TEST_VIEW;
   RETURN ''Test snapshot for March'';
end;
';
```

Comment: we can ignore the return statement right? or do we have to return something.

Comment: It's always a best practice to return something.

Comment: i tried the folllowing:
'begin set dt = current_date(); set table_suffix = (select upper(monthname($dt) || year($dt)); create or replace table test_table_$table_suffix as select 5 as v union select 6 as v; return ''test''; end; '; it gives me an error saying $dt does not exist